# How to add a HTML element in ADMIN edit post window?

Tags: hooks

I'm a newbie to WordPress plugin development. I'm creating a plugin that will fetch a image from some APIs such to flickr and store its values such as its URL in the database. And that particular image will be displayed to the end user along with the content.

Now, I'm trying to create a feature in my plugin which lets the user to see the preview of the image in the admin post window once it is published (in the edit post window).

But I couldn't able to identify any hooks for making that preview in the admin edit post window.

Is there any hooks to add a HTML image tag in the admin edit post window? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work. It will add a meta box below the content editor window which outputs anything you put in the `get_preview_image()` function. I've included the `$post` argument so you can grab info from the post.

If you need this to be on a custom post type instead of posts, edit where it says 'post' in the `image_preview_add_meta_box()` function.

```
add_action( 'some_image_preview', 'get_preview_image', 10, 1 );

function image_preview_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'image_preview-image-preview',
        __( 'Image Preview', 'image_preview' ),
        'image_preview_html',
        'post',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'image_preview_add_meta_box' );

function image_preview_html( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( '_image_preview_nonce', 'image_preview_nonce' );
    do_action( 'some_image_preview', $post );
}

function get_preview_image( $post ) {
    echo 'This is cool!';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I did it myself using `add_meta_boxes`, is there a way to get it on the side like somewhere under format box?

Comment: Replace the 'normal' with 'side' in the image_preview_add_meta_box() function :) If you want it below format, replace 'high' with 'default'.